# VTK smoothing with constraints

Tags: vtk

I'm trying to smooth a vtkPolyData mesh. The mesh has a lot of vertices that are exactly on the mesh's bounding box and I would like to preserve the location of those vertices. In further steps multiple smoothed meshes are stitched together, so the mesh has to have perfectly flat walls at its outer most limits, i.e. on the surface of its respective bounding box.

I have tried to use the vtkSmoothPolyDataFilter and defined a 'source' box as this seems to be the way to define constraints. But instead of preserving the location of the points that are on the box, the algorithm moves ALL the vertices of the mesh to their closest location on the box. So this is clearly not what I am looking for.

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks!
Nils

Comment: Have you seen these methods? http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Meshes/Subdivision I believe some of them don't move any of the original vertices, only introduce new ones. Would that work?